# "Locator strategy 'css selector' is not supported for this session" message appearing when trying to run tests on appium from inteliji

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, appium, appium-ios

Appium inspector works fine. This happens for every test. Appium version 1.9.1. 
No css selectors are in the code so it shouldn't be returning this message.
Tried 1.9.1 beta version also returning the same issue 
Running on ipad4 mini, ios12.

Comment: If you can provide more details then we can help you. Share the problem test code, capabilities used and Appium error logs.

Comment: Were you able to solve this?